# get zxing data into swipe view fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I am using zxing in a fragment of viewpager tab. I can call zxing with Intent and read the QR code but I can't get result to a edittext.

This is where i create tab in FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2();
        default:
            return new EmptyTab();
        }
    }
```

And my **Tab1** class:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        IDEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fttx_id_editText);

        Button scanBarcode = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_barcode);

        scanBarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            // we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            IDEditText .setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

zxing starts; then reads; then ends; but with no scan data: I think 'onActivityResult' never starts :(

How can i use zxing in this fragment?

Comment: Are you also overriding `onActivityResult()` in your Activity, or just the Fragment? If you are, you should call `super.onActivityResult` which will push the result to any Fragments.

Comment: @ataulm; I just use 'onActivityResult()' in my fragment; not override in my Activity.

Comment: do a toast text to the first part of the if statment to see if it gets there, and tell us

Comment: @ataulm; I overide it now in Activity with 'super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);' but didnt work.

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous; I did it, but it never get in to 'onActivityResult'

Comment: did you add the package to the manifest?

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous; Yes i have '<activity android:name="com.example.tabfragment.Tab1"/>' in manifest.

Comment: @Kuvalya You cant add fragment to manifest. can you please add the project somewhere online so i can download it and check it? And you want to start barcode app or integrate the activity to your app?

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous; sorry, i cant upload all project. but before you asked, i didnt have package in manifest. Then I try 'com.example.tabfragment' and then "com.example.tabfragment.Tab1' but both of them didnt work.

Comment: wait, is Tab1 an activity or a fragment? color me confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntentIntegrator` has another constructor, taking the Fragment. Instead of:

```
scanBarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
});
```

you can use:

```
scanBarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(Tab1.this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
});
```

and it should invoke `onActivityResult` for the Fragment directly.

An example showing working usage of both starting the intent from an Activity and from a Fragment, with the barcode scanner installed, [is demonstrated in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/ataulm/android-basic/tree/zxing/app/src/main/java/com/ataulm/basic).

---

If you are using the v4 support library Fragments, the [`IntentIntegratorSupportV4`](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegratorSupportV4.java?r=2122) class provides compatibility:

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegratorSupportV4(Tab1.this);
```

Comment: Yess.. It's working now :) I am using support lib; so I used IntentIntegratorSupportV4 constructor. THX.

Comment: Which version are you using? I am using version 3.2.1 of the IntentIntegrator and there is no IntentIntegratorSupportV4 constructor.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your manifest

```
    <!-- Zxing scan activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
```

and then change the onclick method to this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CaptureActivity.class);
    intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    // this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's
    // history
    intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and finally change the on result to this

```
if(requestCode==0)
    if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I dont have CaptureActivity in my project. I just use 'IntentIntegrator' and 'IntentResult' of 'com.google.zxing.integration.android' package.

Comment: CaptureActivity is at the zxing library project

Comment: @ataulm because i wanted to add the zxing scan activity to my app and not just open barcode scanner app

Answer (score 2):

For newer Zxing BarcodeScanner library. `IntentIntegratorSupportV4(Fragment.this)` is not available. You can use this.

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(Fragment.this);
 integrator.initiateScan();
```