# zxing not returning code?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am trying to code that zxing can read a barcode and returns the value to one of the text fields.
I am following this file:[Fragment example](https://github.com/ataulm/android-basic/blob/zxing/app/src/main/java/com/ataulm/basic/StartScanningFromFragmentActivity.java)
The application will launch and it will be copied to the clip board, but the numbers will not appear in the TextFiled.

Here's my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/TabFirst">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="First Tab"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/boxCodeInput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTest"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonTest"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonTest" />
```

and Here's ma java file:

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class first extends Fragment {

private EditText text1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container, false);

    text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.boxCodeInput);

    Button firstButton ;

    firstButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);

    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){


}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String scanData = (scanningResult != null) ? scanningResult.getContents() : "";

    if (scanData == null || scanData.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TryAgain!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        text1.setText(scanData);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is it even getting into Activity result of Fragment?

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680863/get-zxing-data-into-swipe-view-fragment also this http://androide-examples.blogspot.in/2013/11/zxing-onactivityresult-called-only-in.html

Comment: have you checked that your "onActivityResult" is getting called or not ?

Answer (score 0):

After moving *onActivityResult* to main, it worked.
Thanks everyone!